# How to raise an event from a dialog with a string parameter

Tags: nao-robot, pepper, choregraphe

I want Pepper to play a video if I told him to do so (in a dialog). Currently I have implemented an behavior that plays videos. This video player is activated by an event named "Video/PlayVideo" and it plays the video provided by this event (the name of the video as a string parameter).

So how can I do it in my dialog? Below I have added an example how I am expecting this event to be called but I am not sure it could be done and how exactly the syntax is:

**Edited:**

```
u:(Start video) OK, I will start the video ^raisePlayVideoEvent("my_video.mp4")
```

This `^raisePlayVideoEvent` is supposed to be an event from `ALMemory`.
Also it could be 'LeftBumperPressed("my_video.mp4")' - event when left bumper pressed raised with the parameter "my_video.mp4".

Comment: See the documentation, I remember there's something to store data, like $1 or ... to be combined wuth a '*' to catch the video name...

Comment: My problem is focused not on storing the date but on raising the event with parameter. I will edit the code above because it's a little bit ambiguous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To raise an event in dialog use `$Video/PlayVideo=value` (see [qiChat documentation](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-5/naoqi/interaction/dialog/dialog-syntax_full.html#variable)).

By storing a value in an ALMemory key you are effectively also raising the event of the same name.